# Polygons such that $n^2 $ times magnification of a polygon could be covered by exactly $n^2$ original polygon

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

While studying about covering problems in combinatorics, I got to a simple question:

What polygons can be covered exactly, without any area that is covered twice or area that is outside the covered area?

For example, all parallelogram that is $n^2$ times magnified can be exactly covered by original parallelogram, as following.

[image]

Are there any research known about this property, such that the polygon can be exactly covered by original polygon when magnified $n^2$ times?

Comment: I think this only works for triangles and some quadrilaterals. The moment you have a polygon with more than $4$ sides you run into problems with the  angles.

Comment: Stick three equal squares together in an L shape. You can fit four of those in an L magnified by 2, nine of them into an L magnified by 3, and, for all I know, for every $n$, $n^2$ of them into an L magnified by $n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the example. I was trying to draw something like that and wasn't able to do so, so I wrongly concluded that it is impossible in general.

Comment: Seems related: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rep-tile although here it is only asked for one and not all $n$.